# How many Proficiencies should I have?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, proficiency

I playing am a Shifter (Wildhunt), Druid (Circle of the Shepherd) with a Gruul Anarch background. I am not sure how many Proficiencies I should have. Please help me get the right number.

Comment: Oh, also Welcome to RPG Stack Exchange! Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already, and check out the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for additional help.

Comment: I tagged your question as D&D 5e, as that game has a Druid subclass called Circle of the Shepherd, Race called Shifter (Wildhunt), and Background called Gruul Anarch. Let us know if that is not right.

Comment: What research have you done to answer the question? In what does your uncertainty lie?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### You should have 7 proficiencies (2 tools, 5 skills)

I'll assume your character is level 2, as you only get to pick your Druid Circle on second level, so you will have no ability score increases yet to buy (optional) feats that could provide additional proficiencies.

The **Shifter (Wildhunt)** race gives you the Natural Tracker feature that provides a proficiency:

> ***Natural Tracker***. You have proficiency in the Survival skill.

Count: 1, running total 1

As a **druid** (of any subclass) you get the following proficiencies (*PHB* p. 65):

> **Armor**: Light armor, medium armor, shields (druids will
> not wear armor or use shields made of metal)
> **Weapons**: Clubs, daggers, darts, javelins, maces,
> quarterstaffs, scimitars, sickles, slings, spears
> **Tools**: Herbalism kit
> **Skills**: Choose **two from** Arcana, Animal
> Handling, Insight, Medicine, Nature, Perception,
> Religion, and Survival

We'll ignore the weapon and armor proficiencies for this discussion and just focus on tools and skills. If you want to count them, add 3 for armor proficiencies and 10 for weapon proficiencies (although the count there is a bit iffy, as many classes like the fighter have proficiency in "simple weapons" or "martial weapons", which includes a large number of weapons in the core rules. So counting every individual weapon one is unlikely to be that helpful.)

Count: +3 (1 tool, 2 skills), running total 4, assuming you are smart enough to not to pick the Survival proficiency that you already have from your race. Also avoid picking Animal Handling, as you will get that from your background (see below).

The Circle of the Shepard features do not gain you any additional proficiencies when you get them on level 2.

The **Gruul background** gives you the following proficiencies

> **Tool Proficiencies**: Herbalism kit
> **Skill Proficiencies**: Animal Handling, Athletics

You already have Herbalism kit from your class, but the rules on backgrounds (*PHB* p. 125) allow you to change this

> In addition, most backgrounds give a character proficiency with one or more tools. Tools and tool proficiencies are detailed in chapter 5. If a character would gain the same proficiency from two different sources, he or she can choose a different proficiency of the same kind (skill or tool) instead.

So check with your DM if they are OK to replace the tool proficiency for another one. It should not normally be an issue. If you did not pick Animal Handling for your class, you get it added here.

Count: +3 (1 tool, 2 skills), running total 7

Comment: So in your opinion what should I have checked (I'm using foundry forge)

Comment: @capricornuss what you should have checked is up to you mostly but you should have 5 normal skills checked, and 2 tool proficiencies. Some of those should be fixed (like herbalism kit and animal handling) but many DM's don't care if you use the right lists as long as you have the right amount of skills overall. If you are asking this last part because you don't know how to do it in foundry forge I would consider a separate question for that as it likely needs certain expertise.

Comment: @capricornuss what do you mean by saying "I'm using foundry forge" in your comment.

Comment: @SeriousBri so i should naturally have survival, animal handling and athletics. and add 5 on top of that?

Comment: Also im lvl 3, i forgot to mention that

Comment: @capricornuss For tools you would have Herbalism kit. Youd then add 3 more: two more skills from the druid selection - Perception is probably the most often rolled one from these, but what is good also depends on your character idea and what other people in the group have. And one more tool proficiency that makes sense.

Comment: Level 2 or 3 does not make a difference here. On level 4 you‘ll get to pick a feat, and could pick skilled which would give you more skill proficiencies (but, you are probably better off just increasing your Wisdom by 2,  or getting another feat, it's not a great feat).

Comment: also i get the 2 tool kits, but im talking just basic Proficiencies, like which i should naturally have like Survival. And which i need to add/should get.

Comment: @capricornuss  I don't have a discord, sorry. There is no such thing in the game as "basic" proficiencies. What you probably mean is "skill proficiencies". Of those, you get only 5, and 3 of them are pre-set as Survival, Animal Handling, and Athletics. You can pick 2 more, but not just anything: only from the list of those given for druids, which leaves you to pick 2 from Arcana, Insight, Medicine, Nature, Perception, Religion.

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin i finally understand thank youuuuuuuuu

Comment: @capricornuss: Have you read through the [Basic Rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules), particularly chapter 1?